# MongoDB: Shell script to Take automatic hot backup in Mongodb

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell, database-backups

I have written below shell script for taking automatic backup . Now if i want to take hot backup how to write the script. I know we need to use db.fsyncLock(). But how to use it in the shell script. Please let me know as I'm new to shell scripting.

```
#bin!bash
DIR=`date +%m_%d_%y:%H:%M:%S`
cd /opt/mongo/bin
./mongodump --port 27020 --db db --out /data/mongo/backup/$DIR
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a directory "auto_backup".
2. Create "autobackup.sh"

> DIR=`date +%d%m%y`
>
> DEST=auto_backup/$DIR
>
> mkdir $DEST
>
> mongodump -d  -o $DEST

3. chmod +X autobackup.sh
4. Go to cron tab 
   in Ubuntu

> sudo crontab -e

in centos

> sudo vim /etc/crontab

m h dm M dw UserName     Path of your .sh file

1 0 *  * *  username /home/username/auto_backup_script.sh

> m: Minutes (0-59)
>
> h: Hours (0-23)
>
> dm: Day of Month (1-31)
>
> M: Month(1-12)
>
> dw: day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
>
> username: System Username

Save it.

and Restart your cron service.

Answer (score 0):

Below script helps me with it:

DIR=`date +%m_%d_%y:%H:%M:%S`
cd /opt/mongo/bin
./mongo admin --eval "printjson(db.fsyncLock())"
./mongodump --port 27020 --db db --out /data/mongo/backup/DIR
./mongo admin --eval "printjson(db.fsyncUnlock())"